# Show that $\sqrt{-1} \notin \mathbb{F}_7$

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields

I'm doing some group theory tasks and I need to show that $\sqrt{-1} \notin \mathbb{F}_7$. I'm really not sure how to achieve this, and this is my attempt so far:

$\mathbb{F}_7=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$

$x = \sqrt{-1} \\
x^2 = -1 \\
x^2 + 1 = 0$

I'm not sure where to go from here, because I can't factor $x^2+1$ any further. I hope someone can help me with this, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can simply try all of the elements of $\mathbb{F}_7$ and see that none of those, squared, gives $-1$

Comment: An answer based on elementary group theory might be to observe that $\sqrt{-1}$ is necessarily of order four in the multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_7^*$. But, that group has six elements so by Lagrange's theorem cannot have elements of order four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

$$\mathbb{F}_7 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

Now just take any of these numbers and compute $x^2+1$. Show that nothing equals zero

Comment: I understand now. Thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{F}_7$ has seven elements: $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. In this case, given the small number of elements, it is simpler to observe that $-1=6$ since $1+6=0$, and then just square all the elements to show $x^2 \neq 6$ for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_7$.

Answer (score 1):

A prerequisite to group theory is elementary number theory. So we might know that the Legendre symbol is
$$
\left( \frac{-1}{7} \right)=(-1)^{\frac{7-1}{2}}=-1.
$$
Hence $-1$ is not a square in $\Bbb F_7$.

Comment: I hate to admit that I do not understand anything. Where are these equalities hold? clearly not in $\mathbb{R}$ so I'd guess in $\mathbb{F}_7$, but then how do you divide by $7$? and how you derive from this that $-1$ is not a square?

Comment: @Yanko This is the Legendre symbol $(a/p)$. If it is $1$, then $a$ is a square in $\Bbb F_p$, and if it is $-1$, it is not. Have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).